# MySQL select top X records for each individual in table

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Is there a better way to get multiple "top X" results from a MySQL table? I'm able to accomplish this easily with a union when the number of different *foo* is small:

```
(SELECT foo,score FROM tablebar WHERE (foo = 'abc') ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10) 
UNION 
(SELECT foo,score FROM tablebar WHERE (foo = 'def') ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10)
```

I could obviously keep adding unions for each value of foo. However, this isn't practical when there are 500+ different values for foo and I need the top X of each.

Comment: Doubtfully there is a solution that even near to the current one by performance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sort of query can be rephrased in a "greatest-n-per-group" sense, where you want the top 10 scores per "group" being values of 'foo'.

I suggest you have a look at [this link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) that deals with this question marvellously, starting off with a way that makes sense to perform your query and gradually optimising it.

```
set @num := 0, @foo := '';
select foo, score
from (
   select foo, score,
      @num := if(@foo = foo, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @foo := foo as dummy
  from tablebar
  where foo IN ('abc','def')
  order by foo, score DESC     
) as x where x.row_number <= 10;
```

If you wanted to perform this across *all* levels of `foo` (i.e. imagine doing a `GROUP BY foo`), you can omit the `where foo in ...` line.

Basically the inner query (`SELECT foo, score FROM tablebar WHERE foo IN ('abc','def') ORDER BY foo, score DESC`) grabs `foo` and `score` from the table, ordering first by `foo` and then score descending.

The `@num := ...` just increases every row, resetting to 1 for each new value of `foo`. That is, `@num` is just a row number/rank (try running the inner query on its own to see what I mean).

The outer query then selects rows where the rank/row number is less than or equal to 10.

NOTE:

Your original query with `UNION` removes duplicates, so if the top 10 scores for `foo='abc'` are all 100 then only one row will be returned (since the `(foo,score)` pair is replicated 10 times). This one will return duplicates.

Comment: Works great, thanks much - I had actually stumbled upon the page you linked in my searching but at quick glance mistakenly thought it was only for displaying the single best row of each group. Guess I should have given it a closer look.