# N-per-group with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to replicate the logic as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442527/how-to-select-the-newest-four-items-per-category/1442867#1442867). However, I'm not having any luck when there are joins. Below is a minimised version of my query:

```
SELECT resources.title, catRel.catRef
FROM resources 
LEFT JOIN placesRel ON placesRel.refId = resId 
LEFT JOIN catRel ON refId = resId
WHERE ...
```

In short, I'm getting a list, which contains category Ids and I want to limit the results to have no more than *n* results from a category, for example, show only two results per catRef:

```
title             catRef
Swizz Gubbinz     1
Runcible Spoons   1
Peter Pan DVD     2
Button Moon       2
Monkey Alan       3
Bilge Pump        3
```

Comment: Are title and catRef both from resources?

Comment: I've updated the thread to be a little more specific, as the output example I give suggested I was looking for catRef = 2. title is in resources and catRef is in catRel.

Comment: You are using mysql.  This is easy using the row_number() function, which mysql does not (yet?) support.  If you only want two values, I might suggest doing a group by, and doing the min() and max() on a single row.

Comment: [Here is a good article about mimicking row_number() functionality in mySql](http://www.explodybits.com/2011/11/mysql-row-number/). Once you have a row_number() per group you can simply filter records with rn <= 2 or whatever you need at the moment.

Comment: Could you provide full query and relevant table definition?

Comment: Thank you all for your time nd advice. I'm not on the computer now, but it sounds like one or all of the suggested solutions will work.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back and the first answer here worked well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969126/mysql-select-top-x-records-for-each-individual-in-table

Comment: Thank you Exupery. That has done the trick.

Comment: Having looked into it a bit further the solutions provided by Nikola and Exupery only work when there are no join. Otherwise you get something like this:

   title       catRef       rowNumber
   Item1       1            1
   Item2       1            2
   Item3       1            3
   Item4       2            1
   Item5       1            1

i.e. it gets processed as it comes out of the DB, rather than being ordered on the column you want to group by.


Investigating....

Answer (score 2):

How about using an subquery within your join. I wasn't sure which table refID and resID belonged to but.....

```
SELECT resources.title, catRel.catRef
FROM resources 
LEFT JOIN placesRel ON placesRel.refId = resId 
LEFT JOIN catRel as cr1 ON cr1.catRel.primaryKey in (select cr2.primaryKey from catRel as cr2 where cr2.refID = resId Limit 0,2)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: haven't tested this- but it's what I'd try, maybe with an "order by" clause in the subquery

Answer (score 0):

In the lack of Window Functions from MySQL, the answer is not trivial.
Here's a trick which selects top N record per group, by utilizing MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT:
[MySQL: Selecting Top N Records Per Group](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/sql-selecting-top-n-records-per-group).

Being an aggregate function, GROUP_CONCAT can be manipulated to provide with concatenated strings in desired order. Using text manipulation, the string is parsed. Optionally, values are cast to proper types.