# MySql - apply limit to joined rows only

Tags: mysql

Consider the following query:

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.name
     , p.id
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN posts p
    ON p.id IN(
SELECT x.id 
  FROM posts x 
 WHERE x.user_id = u.id
ORDER 
    BY x.featured DESC 
LIMIT 10
);
```

I am trying to join the posts table to the users table. However I only want to retrieve a maximum of 10 posts per user.

This approach throws the following error:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Is there an alternative approach to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Whenever possible, take a moment to analyze your queries. When written correctly, subqueries can greatly reduce the amount of overhead and execution time. Since you are using an older MySQL version I believe you can `set profiling = 1;`, `enter query here;` `show profiles;`. from the cmd prompt or MySQL Workbench. You can use the `DESCRIBE` keyword or `SHOW PROCESSLIST` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL select top X records for each individual in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969126/mysql-select-top-x-records-for-each-individual-in-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu)

Answer (score 0):

You should use an inner join on subquery instead of left join and IN clause

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, t.id
FROM users
INNER JOIN (
SELECT posts.id, posts.user_id
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY posts.featured DESC 
LIMIT 10 ) t on t.user_id  = users.id
```

In this way you don't use a limit inside a In clause for subquery and this should not raise the error  .. the error for both `LIMIT & IN ....`  but not for athe sue of in limit in subquery in JOIN  (withou IN clause)

Comment: This is a better approach but he also needs an alternative to LIMIT

Comment: @yardpenalty  This should work because the LIMIT is not   used  inside a subquery for IN clause  ..the error message if for   "LIMIT & IN ...."

Comment: [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) Gotcha! I didn't look closely enough...Maybe edit your answer on how this eliminates his   limitation on the ability to use the `LIMIT` with `IN/ALL/ANY/SOME`. Well done sir.